# swiftUI NavigationLink not taking me to the correct View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have the following:

```
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(events) { event in
                        VStack {
                            Image(event.image)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .padding(55)
                            NavigationLink(destination: PostView()) {
                            Text(event.name)
                                .font(.system(.headline))
                                .padding(.bottom,20)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                        .cornerRadius(10)

                }
            }
        }
```

But the NavigationLink `NavigationLink(destination: PostView()) {` doesn't take me to the correct view?

Ii have tried wrapping the NavigationLink around the each VStack but that also doesn't take me to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is you don't have using "NavigationView".

```
NavigationView{
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) {_ in
                        VStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: PostView()) {
                            Text("event.name")
                                .font(.system(.headline))
                                .padding(.bottom,20)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                        .cornerRadius(10)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```